# How do I access the value of a slot in a Svelte 3 component?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I've been playing around with Svelte 3. I'm trying to create a basic Link component that's used like this:

```html
<Link to="http://google.com">Google</Link>
```

My component renders a normal HTML `<a>` tag with a favicon in front of the link text:

```html
<script>
  export let to
  const imageURL = getFaviconFor(to)
</script>

<a href={to}>
  <img src={imageURL} alt={`${title} Icon`} />
  <slot />
</a>
```

The `title` variable I'm showing in the alt attribute for my `<img>` tag needs to be the text value of the unnamed slot. This is a really basic example, but is there any way to get the value of a slot like this?

Comment: Just use title prop, same as the "to" prop, rather than slot.

Comment: I understand that, but that's only a workaround. That's not how links work, and this isn't the only time when it would be useful to have access to the children of a component.

Comment: Well it is not a workaround, the slot creates a data channel through which you are able send content into the slot context, it is not a simple property. You would have to leverage some svelte internals to read the slot context data. Try to create a slot in the https://svelte.dev/repl/ and see the JS output, how the channels are being compiled.

Answer (score 9):

In the mean time I found another (even better and not so hacky) way:

```
<script>
  export let to
  let slotObj;
  const imageURL = getFaviconFor(to)
</script>

<a href={to}>
  <img src={imageURL} alt={slotObj? slotObj.textContent + ' Icon' : 'Icon'} />
  <span bind:this={slotObj}><slot/></span>
</a>
```

Comment: This will not be reactive to textContent modifications.

Comment: how to do this in 2001?

Answer (score 3):

This hack will work.

Add a hidden span or div to bind the slot text:

```
<span contenteditable="true" bind:textContent={text} class="hide"> 
    <slot/>
</span>
```

And update your code like this:

```
<script>
  export let to
  let text;
  const imageURL = getFaviconFor(to)
</script>

<a href={to}>
  <img src={imageURL} alt={text + ' Icon'} />
  {text}
</a>
```